# Undefined _POST variable when using XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I am trying to use Ajax to insert data into database with POST method. But php can not recognize the post variables.

ajax:

```
function createUser() {
var _id=document.getElementById('new_id').value;
var _name=document.getElementById('new_name').value;
var params = "id="+_id+"&name="+_name;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xmlhttp);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if(xmlhttp.responseText=="")
            alert("New User is created!");
        else
            document.body.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST","resource/create_profile.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

php:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];  
$conn = oci_connect(....);  
$query = "....";  
$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($result);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

if i uncomment the request header content type then nothing happens, no error is shown. if i comment it then php shows error. i am giving a screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u12nG.jpg

what am i supposed to do? if i use get method then it is working good but i can not use it since i need to upload file.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Your data is probably being sent via GET and will exist in the `$_GET` object. You need to change it to use POST.

Comment: i have used firebug console and there i can see the post request contains the data.i am giving a screenshot.

http://imgur.com/CdKO84V

Comment: Whats in `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: i have used $_Request too..no luck.

Comment: You probably need to encode the data you're sending in Javascript or something. If PHP has nothing in any of the request superglobals then you've done something wrong on the client

Comment: in the last line of ajax code if i write  
  
    xmlhttp.send("id=123&name=ggg");  
  
then in the php file i should get the id value by    $id=$_POST["id"]; am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I have found the solution! I had to add the setRequestHeader() method below the open method. So in the end the code looks like:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","resource/create_profile.php",true);  
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```